# Printing principal features in clusters (python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a mxn matrix, with m features and n samples. The matrix is called `term_individual`. The clustering is done using scikitlearn:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
kmeans.fit(term_individual.T)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_.squeeze()
labels = kmeans.labels_
```

Each sample is a vector filled with positive integer numbers. If the i-th component of a sample is n, it means that the i-th feature is present n times in that sample.

I would like to know the most representative features of each cluster. For instance, suppose that the i-th feature is present many times in the first and second sample, causing these samples to be in the same cluster along with many others in which the i-th feature is present as well. I would like to print that feature (or the index associated with it, i.e. print i).

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the question you're asking is which features are most important to each cluster. Essentially you can just start estimating the zscore mean values of each feature in each cluster:

```
def cluster_feature_importance(X, Y, feature_importances):
    N, M = X.shape
    X = scale(X)

    out = {}
    for c in set(Y):
        out[c] = dict(
            zip(range(N), np.mean(X[Y==c, :], axis=0))
        )

    return out
```

Here `X`is your matrix `term_individual` and `Y` as a list informing which cluster each sample belongs to e.g. like so: `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, ...]` where `Y` is `n` long.

Comment: To see if I understand out[c] is a dictionary of keys being the indices of the features, and values being the z-scores of each feature, respectively. The features with the highest z-score (or lowest as well?) will be the most important features. Right?

Comment: Close. out[c] is a dictionary of keys for features and values which are standardized mean values of features in cluster c. The idea is that since we go through the trouble of standardizing (i.e. zscoring) then if the mean value of a feature for points in a specific cluster deviates a lot from 0 (>±1 std) then it probably means that it is important for that cluster.